# Function won't work, says it's not defined?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to use this code, to calculate an area cost. I am using the functions option but it says that `cost` is not defined, I did define it.

```
def space():
    """ This function will calculate the area of floor, that needs 
    flooring. """
    
    # asking for variables
    length =int(input('Please enter the length of the room in meters: '))
    width =int(input('Please enter the width of the room in meters: '))
    
    area=length*width
    
    return area

def flooring():
    """This function will take the flooring chosen by the user and will
    return the cost of the square meter."""
    
    while True:
        # asking for variables
        opt=int(input('Please select type of flooring: '))
        if (opt>=1 and opt<=5):
            break
        
    if (opt==1):
        price=18.75
    ...        
        
    return price
    
def cost():
    """This will calculate the cost of the flooring, and other costs, and
    will display them, aligned."""
    print(price)
    matCost=area*price
    print("$",matCost)  

###
### MAIN PROGRAM
###

while True:
    ...
    
    space()
    print()
    
    print('Types of Flooring')
    print()
    print('                Cost per sq.m.')
    print('1. Low Pile Carpet     $18.75')
    ...
    
    flooring()
    print()
    cost()
```

The error says but I thought I already defined it. With the if statement for the opt, I had thought that I already defined.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"main.py", line 80 in <module>
    cost()
  File"main.py", line 52 in <module>
    print(price)
NameError: name 'price' is not defined
```

Comment: Where is `price` defined *in `cost`* (or globally)? I see no definition of `price` visible to `cost`. For that matter, I don't see where `cost()` is called, which means this isn't a [MCVE].

Comment: @Shadow `cost()` is called in the last line. But otherwise you're right, `price` is obviously not visible to `cost()`, and this code is definitely not minimal.

Comment: The error message says **`price()`** is not defined, not `cost()`. This is because a variable by that name is not defined in that function (nor globally). `flooring()` define a *local* variable by that name, but it's not visible to `cost()`.

Comment: @wjandrea: Oops, missed the scroll bar. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to add price on the `def cost():`

```
def cost(price):
    """This will calculate the cost of the flooring, and other costs, and
    will display them, aligned."""
    print(price)
    matCost=area*price
    print("$",matCost)  

price_result = flooring()
cost(price_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the price variable is defined inside of a function, It is not global.
Instead of attempting to call the price variable directly, you must call to the flooring method which returns said price variable.

```
def cost():
    """This will calculate the cost of the flooring, and other costs, and will display them, aligned."""
    price = flooring()

    # The area variable is also not defined outside of the space method so it would be a good idea to add this as well.
    area = space()
    print(price)
    matCost=area*price
    print("$",matCost)
```

To fix the repeated asking of floor type:

In the following block of code the `print(flooring())` statment is calling the flooring function therefore, re running the `input()`

To fix this you must change the following code blocks:
(read the comment!)

```
while True:
    ...
    
    space()
    print()
    
    print('Types of Flooring')
    print()
    print('                Cost per sq.m.')
    print('1. Low Pile Carpet     $18.75')
    ...
    
    # Set price variable to the flooring() method the first time you call it!
    price = flooring()
    print()
    cost()
```

After setting the global price variable, use it in the function as shown:

```
def cost():
    """This will calculate the cost of the flooring, and other costs, and
    will display them, aligned."""

    #using the global price variable
    print(price)
    matCost=space()*flooring()
    print("$",matCost)
```

Also if you care, just a heads up, When the input flooring type is anything other than 1, the code throws an error so you'll probably want to give print something like "Invalid flooring type":

```
if (opt==1):
    price=18.75
else: 
    price="Invalid flooring type"
```

Comment: It works now, but it's asking for the type of flooring and width and length twice. Because I called for the two functions twice. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: There is no error code. It ask for the length and width. Then for the type of flooring. Then again for the type of flooring. And then it asks again for the length and width, and then it prints the price.

Comment: Yah I realized you meant and updated, (redundant calling) sorry for the late response.